# GetMessage() corrupting my stack?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have had the following function used in a variety of different programs for many years. It has always worked without error. That is until now, when for the first time I attempted to make it work targeting 64bit code.

I try stepping through the code line by line... first of all I execute the line `something_done = TRUE;` which (obviously) sets something_done to 1... which I monitor in the "watch" window. Then I execute `GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0);` ... but somehow during its execution, the variable `something_done` gets set to zero! Subsequently the code then breaks out of the loop and , upon returning from the function call the compiler reports "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'msg' was corrupted."

I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
void process_messages_until_idle()
{
    MSG msg;
    int something_done;
    int temp;

    for (;;)
    {
        something_done = FALSE;

        temp = PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE);

        if (temp)
        {
            something_done = TRUE;
            GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }

        if (!something_done)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I changed something_done into a `static` and now the program crashes somewhere else entirely - in a place that make more sense, so this will probably be easier to debug.

Comment: `PeekMessage` can retrieve the message just as well as `GetMessage` can, the 1-2 step thing isn't necessary.

Comment: I thought that GetMessage would wait forever until something arrived - I want to do something else if there are no messages to be processed.

Comment: Google "doevents considered evil" to get somewhere.

Comment: You don't need `GetMessage` at all, that's my point...

Comment: Doh!... Ok, now I get it.

Comment: Ah, but that then puts the program in an endless loop because you need to scoop the message with getmessage otherwise peekmessage just returns the same thing forever.

Comment: That's a bizarre message loop. What's wrong with using the standard one?

Comment: IIRC It was for when I was in the middle of some super slow calculation but wanted to occasionally allow windows to do its stuff... but I wrote it more than 15 years ago so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It looks wrong. Replace it with a real message loop. If you have to pull messages outside of the main loop, do so with `PM_REMOVE`. Anyway, the code in the question doesn't corrupt the stack. If that happens, it happens in some other code.

Answer (score 1):

Although there was a message when you did PeekMessage, something may have changed.

```
if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        something_done = TRUE;
        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
}
```

Comment: If there is no message, I want the function to return. AFAIK GetMessage() will wait forever.

Comment: PeekMessage takes care of that.  I changed test to `> 0` because of nastiness on window destruction.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on an x64 conversion of a project.  Turned out to be that we had /Zp1 struct member alignment on our project and this was changing the size of the MSG struct from 48 bytes to 40 which then caused stack corruption (and likely other unrealized issues) on x64.  Under Win32 it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are corrupting your stack somewhere. Check which message you were processing at the time the stack was corrupted and inspect its code to see how it breaks.

Comment: This isn't going to help. The particular message retrieved is purely coincidental. There is no relation between the message and the stack corruption. Tools like [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695.aspx) are the way to go forward in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable Tools like that can help but are not the only way to go. Inspecting code works too. In this case the debugger shows the stack corruption during the message processing so it is probably not coincidental. I agree that it is possibly coincidental but there is evidence saying that it's not.

Comment: Even if there is a correspondence between this particular message and the stack corruption, inspecting the stack at the point of message retrieval is too late. The damage is already done. Application Verifier, on the other hand, breaks into the debugger as the corruption happens. It takes you right to the crime scene and hands you the smoking gun. If you don't want to waste time, Application Verifier is the only way forward.

Comment: @IInspectable Nobody is saying "inspect the stack at the point of message retrieval". I said "find which message you are about to process before the stack corruption and inspect its code path". That is a platform/tool independent approach to this class of problem. Application Verifier, valgrind and even BoundsChecker (from the '80s!) all help but are not the only way to go. A smoking gun showing the code path and reasoning about your code is not time wasting. If you depend on tools to show problems like this you fail to reason about your code and it will become more fragile in other ways.

Comment: Application Verifier doesn't implement a magic *Fix me* button. You'll still have to reason about your code. What sort of insight have you gained by following (potentially lots of) dead-ends? And BoundsChecker was developed in the early 90s (in case you *do* care about accuracy).